# How can I highlight an entire pathway in a D3 Sankey diagram?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am building a sankey diagram, like this https://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/ however I need to be able to highlight an entire pathway when the user hovers over the node.

Is there anything built into D3 to do that? If not, how could I do this in Javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by "an entire pathway"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the posted example the hover effect is accomplished through a simple CSS rule for the `:hover` pseudo class.

When the whole path should be highlighted, this isn't as simple anymore. I see **two options**.

### Apply CSS classes to path elements on demand

1. For each path element register a `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` handler
2. In the mouseenter handler read out the data element that is bound to it through d3
3. Calculate the entire path for the read out data element
4. Change the data array for the entire Sankey to carry data about which edges should be highlighted
5. Join the changed data array with the Sankey DOM elements and use the **update selection** to set the `hightlight` class for elements whose bound elements are marked to be highlighted
6. Don't forget to handle `mouseleave` as well

### For each path element set individual classes for paths the element is part of

This option more unconventional. The idea is as follows:

1. When creating the Sankey's DOM elements through the `enter` selection, set individual classes on an element for each path it is part of
2. In a `mouseenter` handler set the currently selected path as a `class` – let's say `hightlight-path-13` if it is path number 13 – on a parent DOM element of the edge elements
3. In CSS have selectors similar to this

   .highlight-path-13 .path-13 {
     stroke-opacity: 0.5;
   }